# TableEditor with Composite does not fit in cell

Tags: java, swt, jface, composite

I tried to create a `TableEditor` with a `Composite` that contains a `Label` and a `Button`. The whole Composite does not fill the cell correctly. It gets trimmed and looks like this (right column):

[image]

Code:

```
@Override
public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
    TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
    Button button;
    Label word;
    ColorKeyWord colorWord = (ColorKeyWord) cell.getElement();

    Composite originalComp = (Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl();

    Composite newComp = new Composite(originalComp, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout laout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    laout.marginHeight = 0;
    newComp.setLayout(laout);
    newComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,true));

    word = new Label(newComp, SWT.NONE);
    word.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true,true));
    button = new Button(newComp,SWT.NONE);
    word.setText(colorWord.getKeyWord());
    button.setImage(prefImage);
    button.pack();
    word.pack();
    newComp.pack();

    TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
    editor.minimumWidth = newComp.getSize().x;
    editor.setEditor(newComp , item, cell.getColumnIndex());
    editor.layout();

}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the exact same problem..

Comment: Unfortunately not.